# What is better to use fo responsive web sites in Boostrap 4? .container or .container-fluid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

What is better to use for responsive designs - .container class or .container-fluid class??

Comment: this is a design decision

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your requirement you should prefer container cause .container class provides a fixed width. .container has fix width for each screen size (xs, sm, md, lg). While .container-fluid expands to fill available width. Hence by using .container-fluid your elements on web page can become distorted. Your .container-fluid elements will resize for every small change in width of the browser.